# Laravel 5.3 job can't read public file

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following problem.

When I call getCountry from a Controller it works perfect but when I call it from a job I'm getting this error

```
The file \"assets/geoip/GeoIP2-City.mmdb\" does not exist or is not readable. at /home/vagrant/proyectos/ghc-l5/vendor/maxmind-db/reader/src/MaxMind/Db/Reader.php:46
```

I don't know why it works in Controllers but not in Jobs. Any idea?

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class SiteHelper {

    public static function getCountry($ip)
    {
        try
        {
            $reader = new Reader('assets/geoip/GeoIP2-City.mmdb');
            $record = $reader->city($ip);
            return $record->country->isoCode;
        }
        catch(\Exception $e)
        {
            Log::error("SiteHelper -> getCountry -> ERROR al detectar IP", ['ip' => $ip, 'exception' => $e]);
            throw $e;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think the problem is with your path. try moving your file to storage directory, so that you have an identical path to file from anywhere (use `storage_path()` to get the path). And, its a good practice to supply a full uri.

Comment: As @VishalSh suggested. I'd prefer using `base_path()` and then the path concurring to your file. :)

Comment: Hello, @VishalSh and prateekkathal thanks for your answers but I still have the same error, from a controller works but not from a job.

InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): The file \"/home/forge/gifthunterclub.com/storage/app/public/geoip/GeoIP2-City.mmdb\" does not exist or is not readable. at /home/forge/gifthunterclub.com/vendor/maxmind-db/reader/src/MaxMind/Db/Reader.php:46

Comment: Is the path correct? Check the permissions to the file, which server are you using?

Comment: @Sergio have you fixed this issue?